# Split Quiz query

Tags: php, split

How could I split this into a multidimensional Array.

1. Question 1

   A) Answer 1
   B) Answer 2
2. Question 2

   A) Answer 1
   B) Answer 2

Comment: please edit you question

Comment: Just did it. Can you help me there?

Comment: What do you want to split? a string of the given format?

Comment: what's your string like ?  Is it have the change line char?

Comment: I used preg_split("/\d+\K/",$string); to split by question "number", but I wish I could split the answers by break line. You know what I mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function parseQuestions($str) {
        $str = preg_replace("/\r|\n|\t/", " ", $str); // Remove line breaks and replace with spaces

        $split_questions = preg_split("/\d+\./", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); // An array containing each question and their answers as a string
        $split_answers = array(); // Array that will contain the final arrays with questions and their answers

        foreach($split_questions as $qkey => $q) { // Parses the question and splits it so [0] is the question and everything following are answers
            $split_answers[$qkey] = preg_split("/[a-zA-Z]\)/", $q);

            foreach($split_answers[$qkey] as $akey => $a) { // Loop that goes through each of the answers and trims off whitespace
                $split_answers[$qkey][$akey] = trim($a);
            }
        }

        return $split_answers;
    }
```

This function will return an array with your questions. Index 0 of the array will be your question, and all following indexes will be the answers. For example, when provided string:

```
1. What is the first letter of the alphabet?
A) no
B) 17
C) A

2. What time is it?
A) 7:02
B) Night Time
C) I don't know
D) Hammer Time!
```

The function will return an array with the following structure:

```
[
    [
        "What is the first letter of the alphabet?",
        "no",
        "17",
        "A"
    ],
    [
        "What time is it?",
        "7:02",
        "Night Time",
        "I don't know",
        "Hammer Time!"
    ]
]
```

Whitespace is removed and ignored, so that should not affect the returned array.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I were looking for, but there's another problem. If I have some "(" into the answer he will split the answer. How to solve it?

Comment: The more specific you get, the less friendly it gets. What is triggering this is that you have a letter followed by a `)`. If your questions will only have uppercase letters to signify each choice (i.e. `A)`, `B)`, and `C)` but not `d)`) then change `/[a-zA-Z]\)/` to `/[A-Z]\)/`. If your questions only have a maximum of 4 answers, those being A, B, C and D, then you can change `/[A-Z]\)/` to `/[A-D]\)/`. If you have an example that you need to be permitted that could help me. If this needs to permit any answer combination then you need some guidelines to be set by whoevers making the questions

Answer (score 0):

the php code could be like this:

```
$array = [
'q1' => [
        'Ans1',
        'Ans2'
        ],
'q2' => [
        'Ans1',
        'Ans2'
        ]
```

];